# Return labels for a node using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do I return all the labels for a node using a Cypher query?
Note that I don't know the node id in advance, I do some sort of index match to get it.

Comment: If your node is bound to identifier `n` you can get its labels with `LABELS(n)`. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can get labels by using the `labels()` method.

Example (Neo4j 2.0):

Lets say you have the "name" property indexed and would like to search on that basis, the following query would give you all nodes and their labels which have name = "some_name"

```
MATCH (r) WHERE r.name="some_name" RETURN ID(r), labels(r);
```

If you know one of the labels of the starting node, that's even better. For some known label called "Label", this query would give you all nodes along with all labels that are associated with the node.

```
MATCH (r:Label {name:"some_name}) RETURN ID(r), labels(r);
```

Need more assistance? Go through the Cypher [docs!](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-labels) for labels()

Comment: Excellent! I have been using the rest interface to get this info, this Cypher call is much better

Comment: Useful question and answer. You should accept this answer !